# Find and replace a href value with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have a HTML file with a load of links in it.
They are in the format
`http:/oldsite/showFile.asp?doc=1234&amp;lib=lib1`
I'd like to replace them with
`http://newsite/?lib=lib1&doc=1234`

(1234 and lib1 are variable)

Any idea on how to do that?

Thanks
P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your examples are correct.

`http:/oldsite/showFile.asp?doc=1234&amp;lib=lib1` should be
`http:/oldsite/showFile.asp?doc=1234&lib=lib1`

and

`http://newsite/?lib=lib1&doc=1234` should be `http://newsite?lib=lib1&doc=1234`

To do the replacement on these, you can do

```
'http:/oldsite/showFile.asp?doc=1234&lib=lib1' -replace 'http:/oldsite/showFile\.asp\?(doc=\d+)&(lib=\w+)', 'http://newsite?$2&$1'
```

which returns `http://newsite?lib=lib1&doc=1234`

To replace these in a file you can use:

```
(Get-Content -Path 'X:\TheHtmlFile.html' -Raw) -replace 'http:/oldsite/showFile\.asp\?(doc=\d+)&(lib=\w+)', 'http://newsite?$2&$1' |
 Set-Content -Path 'X:\TheNewHtmlFile.html'
```

Regex details:

```
http:/oldsite/showFile        Match the characters “http:/oldsite/showFile” literally
\.                            Match the character “.” literally
asp                           Match the characters “asp” literally
\?                            Match the character “?” literally
(                             Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   doc=                       Match the characters “doc=” literally
   \d                         Match a single digit 0..9
      +                       Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)                            
&                             Match the character “&” literally
(                             Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2
   lib=                       Match the characters “lib=” literally
   \w                         Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, etc.)
      +                       Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Read in the file, loop through each line and replace the old value with the new value, send the output to the a new file:

```
gc file.html | % { $_.Replace('oldsite...','newsite...') } | out-file new-file.html
```

Comment: Thanks. I am unsure of how to do the replace. It's a Regex I need I think.